# Django-Channels: Lock critical section in class

Tags: django, multithreading, locking, django-channels

I have a class that extends WebsocketConsumer and thus communicates to the client via a websocket. From my understanding the whole process is event-driven and I have one method that has a critical section (I don't want to get the function triggered again while it still processes).

Can I just use python's builtin `threading` module to lock this section. E.g:

```
import threading
class UserCharacterConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, *kwargs)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def critical_method(self):
        self.lock.acquire()

        try:
            # critical section
            pass
        finally:
            self.lock.release()
```

Or wouldn't this work for Django-Channels because it does not use threads in that way?

Edit: It is sufficient to lock the method only for the current user (or even only the class-instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work in development, but it will break in production because there you usually have multiple processes and maybe even multiple machines (or VMs/containers).

You have to use some shared external datastore. You could use your database for that, but something like Redis would be preferable (e.g. using [Redlock](https://github.com/SPSCommerce/redlock-py)).

It might be worth mentioning that such a lock is a bottleneck that will limit the scalability of your application. I'd check if you can have a per-user lock instead of a global lock.

Comment: Thank you! In my case it is sufficient to lock the method for the user or even the class-instance. Added that to my question. Could you provide some information regarding that case in your answer? Then I can accept it :)